# Background images don't tile enough in mobile safari

Tags: css, ios, mobile, safari

I am having a strange problem with mobile safari. Images that are backgrounds on certain divs do not file all the way across the page, they stop just short of halfway across. They show up fine in safari on the PC and Mac.

site online here:
www.bikramyoga.cz

Answer (score 0):

Tried making the tile 10px wide instead of 1px? It might be an issue with the number of repeats Mobile Safari can handle.

Comment: That doesn't work, and now that I look at my code again, the grey sub-navigation bar is short in the same way, and it is just a background-color.

Comment: Tried removing width:100% on body? There seems to be some issues related to the viewport, since the repeat gets wider in landscape mode.

Comment: it makes no difference if I remove 100% body.